# Rotas com o wildcard (:any) ignorando outros controllers

Tags: codeigniter, route

No arquivo *routes.php* eu defini a seguinte *route*:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'reference/check/$1';
```

Preciso dela pois o primeiro parametro na URL depois do domínio é o nome de usuário (`exemplo.com/{nome_usuario}`). Então realizo checagens na classe Reference.

O problema é que nesse caso todos os outros *Controllers* ficaram inacessíveis, sendo todos sobreescritos pela regra de route como mostrei acima.

Como solução temporária tive que forçar os outros *Controllers* definindo *routes* para eles também, ficando da seguinte forma:

```
$route['home'] = 'home';
$route['login'] = 'login';
$route['register'] = 'register';
$route['(:any)'] = 'reference/check/$1';
```

Existe alguma alternativa que eu possa utilizar para que eu não precise definir novas *routes* sempre que eu crie um novo *Controller*?

Answer (score 0):

até o momento, não há alternativa.
Visto que a tag `(:any)` serve justamente para aceitar qualquer coisa, você precisará informar quais rotas você quer manter como controlador ao invés de redirecionar.